# Prove that at an arbitrarily chosen x the sequence $\frac{\lfloor(nx)\rfloor}{n}$ is bounded.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions, upper-lower-bounds

I solved it using a programming code. The upper boundary is $x$, and the lower one is $\lfloor(nx)\rfloor$. I want to know if my answer is right and if there is a better way to solve it, because all I did was putting so many inputs and observing the answer.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Clarification requested:  Did you intend to be referring to the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound, or a lower bound and an upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

> $\lfloor nx \rfloor \geq n \lfloor x \rfloor$

and of course

> $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$

and thus

> $ \frac{ \lfloor nx \rfloor }{ n } \leq \frac{nx}{n} = x$

> $ \frac{ \lfloor nx \rfloor }{ n } \geq \frac{n \lfloor x \rfloor}{n} = \lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: I think you meant $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$.